# I can't populate a dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, json

I am trying to populate the key value pairs in my dictionary which is inside a list. the list I am trying to populate looks like:

```
item_table = [
    for i in range(jsonData.length) :
        {
        'item_no' : str(item_no[i]),
        'part_no' : str(part_no[i]),
        'description' : str(description[i]),
        'quantity' : str(quantity[i]),
        'unit_price' : str(unit_price[i]),
        'total_price' : str(total_price[i])
    },
]
```

As you see here I am trying to use a for loop inside the list but that gives me an error.
I get the values I am trying to insert from:

```
 for i in range(jsonData.length) :
    unit_market_price[i] = jsonData[i]['unit_market_price']
    unit_market_price[i] = float(unit_market_price)
    markup_percentage[i] = jsonData[i]['markup_percentage']
    markup_percentage[i] = float(markup_percentage)
    unit_price[i] = calculateUitPrice(unit_market_price[i], markup_percentage[i])
    item_no[i] = jsonData[i]['item_no']
    part_no[i] = jsonData[i]['part_no']
    description[i] = jsonData[i]['description']
    quantity[i] = jsonData[i]['quantity']
```

the jsonData is  a JSON object as the name suggests.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  Just use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and create a dictionary each time with the loop

```
item_table = [
    {
        'item_no' : data['item_no'],
        'part_no' : data['part_no'],
        'description' : data['description'],
        'quantity' : data['quantity'],
        'unit_price' : calculateUitPrice(
            float(data['unit_market_price']),
            float(data['markup_percentage'])
        ),
        'total_price' : str(total_price[i])  # <-- !! remember to change this part as your code doesn't currently have a definition on total_price
    } 
    for data in jsonData
]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have attempted is invalid syntax. If you *need* to use list comprehensions, I'll provide a snippet below.

However, for readability's sake, you should consider simply instantiating an empty list and then appending new elements to it in a loop:

```
item_table = []
for i in range(jsonData.length):
    item = {
        'item_no': str(item_no[i]),
        'part_no' : str(part_no[i]),
        'description' : str(description[i]),
        'quantity' : str(quantity[i]),
        'unit_price' : str(unit_price[i]),
        'total_price' : str(total_price[i])
    }
    item_table.append(item)
```

I will also mention that the `len()` function is used in Python to get the length of a list.

As promised in the first paragraph, here is the list comprehension version of the code above:

```
item_table = [
    {
        'item_no': str(item_no[i]),
        'part_no' : str(part_no[i]),
        'description' : str(description[i]),
        'quantity' : str(quantity[i]),
        'unit_price' : str(unit_price[i]),
        'total_price' : str(total_price[i])
    }
    for i in range(jsonData.length)
]
```